# setting property in dispatch_async but property is NULL after block finishes

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I am using the following code to change a property called `topPlaces` inside a view controller. The line `[FlickrFetcher topPlaces]` returns an `NSArray` and my property `topPlaces` is, of course, also an NSArray.

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("flickr topPlace", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    NSArray *topPlaces = [FlickrFetcher topPlaces];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.topPlaces = topPlaces;
    });
});
dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
```

However, after the block finishes executing, if I log the value of `self.topPlaces`, that is still NULL for some reason. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Where exactly are you checking self.topPlaces?

Comment: this code is put into viewDidLoad, I am `NSLog`ing it also in viewDidLoad after the above code. Also if it's not NULL, my view would have shown something, but currently it's not showing anything.

Comment: ut are you `NSLOg`ing after the async code runs of just after the dispatch which is before the FlickrFetcher code runs.

Comment: I am putting it after `dispatch_release`. So I guess the block was still sitting somewhere on the queue and not getting executed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ivar will not be set until after your current method has finished. Your call to `[FlickrFetcher topPlaces]` is running in parallel to your current method and takes a random amount of time to complete. When it is complete, it makes a call back to the main thread, which is executed on the next iteration of the run loop

This means that in your second `dispatch_async()` block you need to call any methods to display the data after setting the ivar.

Comment: I see. Now it's fixed. Also I was not refreshing my view after the data gets loaded. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The first part of this answer is incorrect, it is perfectly safe to release the `downloadQueue` right after `dispatch_async()`ing to it, the queue will only be destroyed once the enqueued block finishes.

Comment: das- After checking, I found that you are correct. I have edited my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please first try to stub `self.topPlaces` like this:

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("flickr topPlace", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    NSArray *topPlaces = [FlickrFetcher topPlaces];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.topPlaces = @[@"test", @"test2", @"test3"];
    });
});
```

Then check the value of `self.topPlaces`. If it is still `NULL` then I would need to ask what lifetime qualifier does your property `self.topPlaces` have (Ex. strong, weak, assign)? If it is `weak` then of course the value of `topPlaces` will be `NULL` after assigning it because there will not be any strong pointers to it. If it is `strong` then the value of `NSArray *topPlaces = [FlickrFetcher topPlaces];` is `NULL` when execution reaches `self.topPlaces = topPlaces;`.

The other thing to consider is that when you perform asynchronous actions, execution on the main thread will continue to execute. So, if you are doing the following...

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("flickr topPlace", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    NSArray *topPlaces = [FlickrFetcher topPlaces];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.topPlaces = topPlaces;
    });
});
NSLog(@"topPlaces = %@", self.topPlaces);
```

Then I would expect `self.topPlaces` to always be `NULL` when it hits the `NSLog` due to the fact that it wont be set until after `[FlickrFetcher topPlaces]` has finished and returned and execution continues into the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()...`. At that point the value should be set. You may want to do something like the following to ensure you are not only setting the property but perform some sort of update action to update your UI after your asynchronous actions have completed...

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("flickr topPlace", NULL);
dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    NSArray *topPlaces = [FlickrFetcher topPlaces];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self updateUIWithTopPlaces:topPlaces];
    });
});

- (void)updateUIWithTopPlaces:(NSArray*)topPlaces {
    self.topPlaces = topPlaces;
    // Perform your UI updates here
}
```